# Append timestamp to csv file in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to generate unique csv files by appending timestamps at the end of the file name.

But for some reason csv file is not generating.

```
String path= @"C:\\Users\Isuruh\source\repos\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\data.csv";
                   FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);
        bool exists = info.Exists;
                library.WriteErrorLog(exists.ToString());
                // Upload data from file
           -->     string result = "data_" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".csv"; 

               if(exists == true)
                    {
                         File.Delete(Path.GetFileName(path));
                sqlRun();
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\Isuruh\source\repos\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\**result**", csv.ToString());


                    }
               else
                    {

                sqlRun();
                      File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\Isuruh\source\repos\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\**result**", csv.ToString());


                    }

        }
```

Comment: The filename is invalid. \**result** is not valid for a file or folder name.

You're not replacing the result variable in the hardcoded path. You could at least, assign it into a variable. This way you only need to change only in one piece of code.

Comment: Are you aware that there are many characters (some which normally appear in a date) are illegal in a file name?

Comment: Nah, that's news for me mate @Plutonix

Comment: That path looks suspicious; you're not trying to write to the folder your app is installed in, are you? No good comes of that; write to `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have forgotten to combine the folder path and the expected filename

Here goes your code refactored (not tested):

```
var folder = @"C:\\Users\Isuruh\source\repos\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\";
var path = Path.Combine(folder, "data.csv");
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);
bool exists = info.Exists;
library.WriteErrorLog(exists.ToString());

// Upload data from file
var result = "data_" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".csv";
var fullResultPath = Path.Combine(folder, result);

if(exists)
{
    // Do you really want to delete the data.csv file ?
    File.Delete(path);
}

sqlRun();
File.WriteAllText(fullResultPath, csv.ToString());
```